# Detect if a cell phone device is reachable or not (switched on/off) programmatically

Tags: android, asp.net, network-programming

I am assigned an absurd task, which is to detect if a cell phone is reachable or not by typing in their numbers.

So its basic use is say I am handling a telephonic service which has around 10,000 agents. By running a program through web or which ever way possible i'll know if a number is switched on/off, since the numbers need to be available 24x7 for the company.(It has other uses as well, telling those would be waste of time for all).

I tried searching on internet but could not get a single hint if it can be achieved or not.
Currently I am going through basics of how a call is established and network in cell phone devices.
For any help,I would highly appreciate since this complete question might sound stupid. 
Even if some can point me to the right direction, do answer.

NOTE :  I have to build an stand-alone application to do the work. Cannot install my own application in devices to send a ping or so, since most of the cell phones a basic low-end devices.

Thanks

Comment: You will need cooperation from the carrier.

Comment: Can't you just ping those devices?

Comment: @SLaks : by carrier do you mean the network providers ?

Comment: Cant you swap the roles? Devices (not server) will periodically ping the server to signal they're on (so you can also detect if they're muted, they were not available because of network problems and so on).

Comment: @shkschneider: i don't know how to do that. Can you share a link ? i tried searching if we can ping a cell phone, but got nothing.

Comment: ping/pong is the simplest protocol system ever. You send a 'ping' and expect a 'pong' as a response. If you got one, that thing on the end of the line, is alive ^^ Can be done in both ways as @AdrianoRepetti specified.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti :  Sorry, i forgot to mention earlier that i cannot install anything on the devices. So it'll be a stand-alone app(hosted on web may be) trying to know if device is available.

Comment: Then I'd take a look to Skype API. You don't need to call, just check if they rings...of course I don't know if this allowed by Skype so you should check. If you want to check without making a call (they'll see it and telephone will ring) then as SLaks said you need help from carrier (contact them directly).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : Thanks for the input :) I'll try and get details on Skype API.

Comment: Hey! Can i build an app on android, feed in the numbers, it'll give a call and automatically disconnect and get details about the calling information whether a call was successful or not. Is it possible ?